# F# SqlCommandProvider defer eval until runtime

Tags: f#, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I am trying to use SqlCommandProvider (part of FSharp.Data.SqlClient) to create a column if it does not exist and then set a constraint (self referencing).  The problems is that it will not compile because it detects that the column as part of the constraint does not yet exist.  I tried wrapping it in another IF block to no avail.

```
[<Literal>]
let CreateParentColumn = "
    IF COL_LENGTH('Company', 'ParentId') IS NULL
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE Company
        ADD ParentId INT

        ALTER TABLE Company
        ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ParentIdCompanyId FOREIGN KEY (ParentId)
        REFERENCES Company(CompanyId);
    END
"

type CreateParentIdColumn  = SqlCommandProvider<CreateParentColumn, connectionString>
```

I would greatly prefer not to use dynamic sql.  I was wondering if there was a way to defer evaluation so that it would run properly (note, the query itself runs fine in SQL Management Studio)

> Error 1   The type provider 'FSharp.Data.SqlCommandProvider' reported an error: Foreign key 'FK_ParentIdCustomerId' references invalid column 'ParentId' in referencing table 'Company'.
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brief answer is *"No, this cannot be done"*.

The more elaborate answer is *"This cannot be done for the fundamental reason: run time database schema features should be already present at compile time in order to be anyhow utilized by* `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` *type provider"*.

Just from the academic interest standpoint, it is not a problem (although a quite unusual practice) creating an extra column and a constraint in a database at run time and there is no need to involve dynamic SQL for this purpose. Can be easily achieved by using plain ADO side by side with type provider:

```
use cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(CreateParentColumn, connectionString)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() |> ignore
```

The actual problem though is that this freshly created column cannot be of any use in `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` type provider context as it does not
exist yet in database schema at compile time to be anyhow utilized by the type provider.

Rephrasing, `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` type provider does not perform any action at run time, its job has been already completed at compile time.

Comment: Very good point.  I find the F# providers to be very useful, but I tend to overuse them.  Thanks.